# can I set a default font for all plots in R?

Tags: r

I would like to change the default font for all plots in R to Times New Roman (without having to specify them per plot). Each plotting command in R has a different setup to change the font, which can make it quite exhausting. Is that possible?

Comment: you can use `par` to set graphical parameters:i.e. `par(font.main=6)` for times new roman in title.